# How can I tell Jekyll to use a subdirectory for article links?

Tags: jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I have a Jekyll blog with the usual directory structure, i.e. a _posts subdirectory containing the posts. The blog is currently accessible by appending `/blog` to the domain root URL (that is, `https://bbs-software.com/blog`). I would like the article URL's to include the blog subdirectory as well, but they currently do not. I am hosting the blog on Github, and the repo is publicly accessible at https://github.com/keithrbennett/keithrbennett.github.io. I have a forward set up to forward `/blog` to `/`. I may want to put something other than my blog at the root of this domain, so I'd like all blog URL's to use the `blog` subdirectory. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by creating a /blog/_posts folder, as explained on this article: https://miklb.com/blog/2016/04/26/organizing-jekyll-posts/